# i want to all attribute value

Tags: php, jquery, xml, xpath

my xml look like this:--->

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <childrens>
            <child1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
                <child2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
                    <child4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
                            </child4>
                    </child2>
            </child1>
            </childrens>
```

i want out put something like this:---> 
Root Catalog 
Navigate 
Activities
this is my code:

```
<?php
$str = '<childrens>
<child1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
    <child2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
        <child4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
                </child4>
        </child2>
</child1>
</childrens>';
$pattern = '/<(.*)="(.*)">/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Comment: Extract them to what?  A multiline string?  A file?  An array?  Are you using an XSLT? A DOM accessor?

Comment: @JLRishe sorry i means i want to get attribute value...

Comment: @jack whathaveyoutried.com means show us what you have tried so far.  What code do you have?

Comment: @JLRishe i am using array

Comment: Then please show us the code.

Comment: @JLRishe check it i have edit my question... thanks for help me better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this:

```
<?php
$str = '<childrens>
<child1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
    <child2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
        <child4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
                </child4>
        </child2>
</child1>
</childrens>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$values = $xml->xpath('//@value');

foreach($values as $value) {
   echo $value."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: its possible using xslt?

Comment: Yes, but an XSLT would either produce a single string value just listing the values (with some additional formatting and content if you need it), or different XML containing the extracted values.  Is either of those sufficient for your needs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411933/use-any-of-client-scripting-language-and-get-the-value

Comment: my actual question is... this above link visit please

Comment: That question has already been closed.  If you want to prevent that from happening, you have to provide an example of what you want to obtain and demonstrate that you have put some effort into it by providing an example of your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Its been ages since i have used jquery but if you have, then i think a crude code to get values might be

```
var selected = $('*[value]'),res =[]; 
for(var i =0;i<selected.length; i++) { 
 res.push(selected[i].value); 
}
```

i am sure you can use a .each with some function to do this in one line, I am just too rusted with jquery to give you that answer

Answer (score 0):

If You have xml file saperated..

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
       {
        var html = '';
        $.get('my.xml', function(d){
           $(d).find('children').each(function(){ 
                   $(this).children().each(getChildNode);
            });
              console.log(html);
             alert(html);
       });

      function getChildNode(obj){
             html += $(this).attr('value') + '\n<br>';
            if($(this).children().length > 0){
                  $(this).children().each(getChildNode); 
             } 
       }

    });

</script>
```

I hope it will work for you.

thanks